# Constant error message in console - reinstall and factory settings doesn't fix

Tags: command-line, error

I am seeing an error message in my Blender console constantly. Not sure if it is affecting performance of Blender or if recent errors in the software have been for other reasons. I have no idea what any of it means but hoping someone here could give me some advice. I have tried a repair installation and reloading factory settings but doesn't stop the error from occurring, even when just doing simple operations in the default scene. I'm a bit concerned it might be a more serious problem with my computer which has crashed recently and I was forced to manually replace some dlls...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender\blender-2.79-windows64\2.79\scripts\startup\RenderStreet\ui.py", line 130, in draw
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender\blender-2.79-rc1-windows64\2.79\scripts\startup\RenderStreet\settings.py", line 27, in __init__
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender\blender-2.79-rc1-windows64\2.79\scripts\startup\RenderStreet\settings.py", line 31, in ParseSettings
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\python\lib\configparser.py", line 696, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\python\lib\configparser.py", line 1077, in _read
    raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: 'C:\\Users\\JohnMcC/.renderst/RenderStreet.ini', line: 1
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Comment: Looks to possibly be a corrupt config file for “RenderStreet”. Is that an add-on you are using?

Comment: Yep, should have seen that but blinded by all that code! Render Street was an add on I used in the past but not recently. It was no longer showing up in listings of my add ons in user preferences but I was able to just delete the Render Street folder from C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\startup. Thanks Rich!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to Render Street trying to read a configuration file. To remove the add-on completely (despite not showing up in User Preferences) remove the Render Street folder from within the `(c:\program files\)Blender Foundation\Blender\(version)\scripts\startup` directory.